# Counting equivalence classe - proof theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

THEOREM: (**Counting equivalence classes**)

Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on a finite set $A$.
If all the equivalence relation of a finite set $A$ have the same size, $m$, then the number of equivalence classes is $|A|/m$.

---

First comment, I think that the number of equivalence class is always $|A|$, because $\forall a \in A : a \in [a]$.
In general we suppose different equivalence classes on $A$ like the theorem. **Is that correct**?

### proof

Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on a finite set A and all the equivalence classes of $R$ have the same size $m$.
So, each equivalence class contains $m$ elements, $[a_1] = \{a_1, a_2, \dots,a_m\}$ and we know (every element is related to itself) $a_1 \in [a_1], a_2 \in [a_2], \dots, a_m \in [a_m]$. Because if $[a_i] \cap [a_j] \neq \emptyset, 1 \leq i < j \leq m$, then $[a_i] = [a_j]$. We have $m$ same equivalence classes.

*Now, I am not sure how continue...*

> It can be question like this. We have 100 beads, and 10 different colours. Each colours have 10 beads (e. g. blue has 10 beads, green has 10 bead, and so
>   on). How many different (by colour) beads we have? Of course answer is
>   100/10 = 10.

How many different equivalence classes we have? - immediately, the answer is $|A|/m$.

---

Can you please check my proof? If it's ok, then please help me reformulate the end of the proof. Else say where is the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument *First comment, I think that the number of equivalence class is always $|A|$, because $\forall a \in A : a \in [a]$.* is not correct.

It is true that $a \in [a]$ for all $a \in A$. However, you can have (as soon a class has more than one element), $a\neq b$ and $[a] = [b]$. This will induce that the number of equivalence classes with be smaller than $\vert A \vert$.

Then regarding the theorem itself. **The equivalence classes form a partition of $A$** (see Fundamental theorem of equivalence relations paragraph in [Equivalence relation - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation)). Therefore if all the equivalence classes have the same number of elements $m$, the number of equivalence classes is $\vert A \vert /m$.

Comment: Yes i agree that number of equivalence classes are not always $|A|$. How can this help with my proof? - After I say *"We have  $m$ same equivalence classes"*, then say - This induce that the numbef of equivalence classes with be smaller than $m$ factor, so we have $|A|/m$. But I need say, what is the $|A|$. Can I say this is maximum number of  equivalence classes?

Comment: @Kapur See my updated answer.

Comment: So I can the theorem (in main post) rewrite in partition like this: *Let $P$ be a partition on a finite set $A$. If all the parts of $P$ have the same size $m$, then the number of parts is $|A|/m$*. And now is nothing to prove, beacuse answer is immediately $|A|/m$ parts. Therefore $|A|/m$ equivalence classes. Can be this another version of proof?